# Angularjs conditional Wizard

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, wizard

I'am developping a form and there is a "Wizard Button" if this wizard button is true, the form is presented as a wizard.

Is there an easy way to avoid code duplication?

As an Example:

```
<wizard on-finish="saveit()" ng-if="data.form.config.wizardmode"> 
 <wz-step title="Starting" ng-if="$index==0 && data.form.config.wizardmode">
   <h1>This is the first step</h1>
   <p>Here you can use whatever you want. You can use other directives, binding, etc.</p>
   <input type="submit" wz-next value="Continue" />
 </wz-step>
 <wz-step title="Continuing">
   <h1>Continuing</h1>
   <p>You have continued here!</p>
   <input type="submit" wz-next value="Go on" />
 </wz-step>
 <wz-step title="More steps">
    <p>Even more steps!!</p>
    <input type="submit" wz-next value="Finish now" />
 </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

If the wizard is off, I would have to write the whole form again?
Is there a good logic (an angular way) basically to hide/display all `<wz-step>` tags?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: you can make a directive for each form

Comment: but I have still two forms?

Comment: you will have 2 forms, but you will only write them once

Comment: ok, sounds cool, do you have an example of this directive? Maybe with the basic logic?

Comment: it is one of the basics of angular js, google custom directives angular js, if you dont find your answer, you can post a question again

Comment: ok,thanks I'll try to go 4 a custom directive

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you are looking for. I've made a plunkr.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eo0kN8Mu1NFBIdGuqssZ?p=preview)

Basically I wrote the wizard directive and it's child directive called wizardStep.

```
<wizard showWizard="showWizard">
  <wizard-step  step-number=1>
    Step 1
  </wizard-step>
  <wizard-step step-number=2>
    Step 2
  </wizard-step>
  <wizard-step step-number=3>
    Step 3
  </wizard-step>
</wizard>
```

Comment: if I use ng-show on the `wizard` tag all the content is hidden, so I have to rewrite the form, or how do you mean?